# How to get a scala Map value, when the key is a tuple in which only the first element is known?

Tags: scala, key, tuples

Suppose I have a scala immutable `Map[(String, Boolean), Set[String]]`, e.g.:

```
val myMap = Map(("a",true) -> Set("b","c"))
```

Now suppose I only know the first element of the key tuple, `"a"`. Can (and how if yes) I get the map's value for this key if:

1) I *know* that the key could either be `("a", true)` or `("a", false)` (there cannot be two keys with the same String as the first element)

2) I *don't know* that, in which case I wish to get some kind of concatenation on the possible two values, such as `v1.union(v2)` or `v1 ++ v2`, etc.

Is there any scala "magic" I could use, like `myMap.get(("a", Any))`?

Comment: My apologies. Design a custom datastructure is too broad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
myMap.collect {
  case (("a",b), s) => s
}.toSet.flatten
```

**UPDATED** (view comments):

If the `myMap` is rather large you can try:

```
Set(myMap.get("a", true), myMap.get("a", false)).flatten.flatten
```

Comment: Linear scan through a Map? I hope the Map is a small one!

Answer (score 9):

In general, hash maps does not work like that, at least efficiently -- you still can scan map linearly and pick first key that matches criteria. In your particular case you can simply try to lookup record twice -- first with `(key, true)`, then if nothing is found `(key, false)`

Comment: So `List(myMap(("a", true)), myMap(("a", false))).flatten`

Comment: @Paul myMap.getOrElse("a" -> false, myMap("a" -> true))

Comment: I did that first, but it's not right, because of this "I don't know that, in which case I wish to get some kind of concatenation on the possible two values, such as v1.union(v2) or v1 ++ v2, etc."

Comment: @Paul hm, frankly speaking I didn't got that second requirement :-(

Comment: Hmm. Should be `List(myMap.get(("a", true)), myMap.get(("a", false))).flatten`. I can't read documentation, apparently

Answer (score 3):

If you have many queries like that, it could be a good idea to replace the map with `Map[String, Map[Boolean, Set[String]]`. It should be easy to see they are equivalent: when you have e.g. `("a", false) -> Set()` and `("a", true) -> Set("a")` in your original map, you'll have `"a" -> Map(false -> Set(), true -> Set("a"))` in the new one.

It is likely to be less memory-efficient, however, especially with these key types. You could improve *this* by replacing `Map[Boolean, Set[String]]` with `(Option[Set[String]], Option[Set[String]])`, where the first field corresponds to `false` and the second one to `true`.

In the case

> 1) I know that the key could either be ("a", true) or ("a", false) (there cannot be two keys with the same String as the first element)

just use `Map[String, (Boolean, Set[String])]`.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey, that's actually what I ended up doing. There was no real reason why the map had to be `Map[(String, Boolean), Set[String]]` in the first place.